# How to get the list of speakers and mics

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

How to get the list of microphones and speakers including default sources as well as those connected externally to the device. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no realiable way of doing that. The Android audio system isn't really designed for apps to have detailed knowledge of all the audio sinks and sources, or to have direct control of the audio routing. You ask to play or record audio, and the exact sink or source will be decided by the routing rules that the device manufacturer has set for that particular use case (also taking into account if you've got any accessories attached).

Comment: That is too bad for Android being such a powerful OS and emerging VOIP world. Suppose User is in a video call and an external mic, speaker and/or HD camera is connected to device(wired or wireless). And user should be able to select audio/video source. isn't  there any way to do so?